# Ethereum disk space needs?

Tags: go-ethereum

What are the disk space requirements for a full sync in Ethereum network in the following cases:

- Main Ethereum Network : 667.10 GB
- Ropsten Test Network  : 26.2 GB
- Kovan Test Network
- Rinkeby Test Network

I google around but I am not able to view recent blockchain size of testnetworks. Main chain size could be found [here](https://bitinfocharts.com/ethereum/).

Comment: Those answers does not include testnet

Comment: And those are old.